# Unity Hand tracking issue on the quest with UI raycasting

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, raycasting, quest

I'm working on a Unity project, trying to test the UI interaction on the Quest II with hand tracking and ray casting.
I've set up a very basic scene with all the default assets (**OVRCameraRig**, **UIHelper**) and added just a button to test the UI interaction.
This is what my scene looks like:

[image]

The issue I have is, when I run the scene, the Ray is rotated 90 degrees, and it's attached to the wrist for some reason. I made a video here to show what I mean :

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5f12yfpugB8](https://youtu.be/5f12yfpugB8)

It's still interacting with the UI though.
Then after watching some online tutorials, I commented out these lines in the **HandInputSelector.cs**, which was attached to the UIHelper:

```cs
void SetActiveController(OVRInput.Controller c)
{
    /*
    Transform t;
    if(c == OVRInput.Controller.LTouch)
    {
        t = m_CameraRig.leftHandAnchor;
    }
    else
    {
        t = m_CameraRig.rightHandAnchor;
    }
    m_InputModule.rayTransform = t;
  */
}
```

and instead added a 2nd script to the UI helper, with these lines only:

```cs
public OVRHand hand;
public OVRInputModule inputModule;
 
private void Start()
{
    inputModule.rayTransform = hand.PointerPose;
}
```

Now the ray is at least attached to the correct position, but it still doesn't rotate properly with the hand movement. I made another video of it here :
Now the ray is at least attached to the correct position, but it still doesn't rotate properly with the hand movement. I made another video of it here :

https://youtu.be/q3d0eG2LwY0

My Unity version is **2021.3.1f1**

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?